# Changing Screen resolution on Samsung Tablet S2 or S3

Tags: screen, screen-resolution

I am preparing to buy my first tablet. It does happen I am shortsighted. In my PC I change the screen resolution to enlarge fonts. I have windows 7.
Is there a way to change screen resolution in Samsung Tablet S2  (Android 5) or Samsung Tablet S3 (Android 7).

Alternatively are there other ways (or apps) - to enlarge fonts ?

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely, you could try out some accessibility features that serve almost a similar goal (as changing resolution in Windows)

You can easily *enable large fonts* or display scaling under *accessibility* in Settings.

Depending on the Android version in question, you can enable large font for example by going to **Settings >> Accessibility >> Large text** e.g on my device

[image] [image]

You can also tweak related settings like enabling or disabling *high contrast* text (varies with android version)

**Settings >> Accessibility >> High contrast text**

> High contrast makes text easier to read on your device. This feature
>   fixes the text colour as either black or white, depending on the
>   original text colour.

Another option to enhance readability of text on your device is using *magnifying option* (in Accessibility) allowing to zoom in or out certain parts of display.

If you looking for third-party applications to do the job try these:

[Big Font (change font size)](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=most.popular.free.font.packs.resize&hl=en)

Or

[Big Font (change font size & display size)](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.a0soft.gphone.bfont&hl=en)

I'm not associated with the above mentioned applications but
 doing a quick googling showed these are most used :)